# Passing a huge parameter to oracle procedure have a performance hit?

Tags: oracle, xmltype

I am having a script as attached, in which I am trying to process/parse XML in a table(STAGE_TBL) in XMLTYPE column and insert the parsed data into another table(PROCESSED_DATA_TBL). The XML can be huge upto 2MB, which results into about 2000+ rows of parsed data. 
The issue I am seeing is when I pass an XML object to a procedure(STAGE_TBL_PROCESS) to parse its taking about 10 seconds per XML, but rather than passing XML if I directly fetch it from table in the procedure(STAGE_TBL_PROCESS) by passing the ID its taking about 0.15 seconds. 
As per document all IN params are passed by reference, then why is this performance variation?

Database Details
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.3.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

Note:I couldn't perform SQL_TRACE or DBMS_STATS as I don't have access to them.

```
/*
This one is taking .15 seconds to process an XML with about 2000 rp_sendRow elements
*/
DECLARE
  CURSOR NewStage IS
        SELECT * 
        FROM STAGE_TBL
        WHERE  status = 'N' 
        ORDER BY PUT_TIME ASC;
      SUBTYPE rt_NewStage IS NewStage % rowtype;

  ROW_COUNT           INTEGER := 0;   -- Return value from calling the procedure
  READ_COUNT          INTEGER := 0;   -- Number of rows read from the stage table
  INSERT_COUNT_TOTAL  INTEGER := 0;   -- Number of Inserts Inven records
  ERROR_COUNT         INTEGER := 0;   -- Number of Inven inserts that did inserted more then 1 row in Inven
  PROCESS_STATUS      STATUS.MmsStatus;
  STATUS_DESCRIPTION  STATUS.MmsStatusReason;
  ERRMSG              VARCHAR2(500);

PROCEDURE STAGE_TBL_PROCESS (IDDATA IN RAW, PROCESS_STATUS OUT VARCHAR2, STATUS_DESCRIPTION OUT VARCHAR2, ROW_COUNT OUT NUMBER) AS 
/*
  This procedure is to parse the XML from STAGE_TBL and populate the data from XML to PROCESSED_DATA_TBL table

  IN PARAMS
  ----------
  IDDATA              -   ID from STAGE_TBL
  xData                 -   XMLType field from XML_DOCUMENT of STAGE_TBL

  OUT PARAMS
  -----------
  PROCESS_STATUS        -   The STATUS of parsing and populating PROCESSED_DATA_TBL
  STATUS_DESCRIPTION    -   The description of the STATUS of parsing and populating PROCESSED_DATA_TBL
  ROW_COUNT             -   Number of rows inserted into PROCESSED_DATA_TBL
*/
BEGIN
     INSERT ALL INTO PROCESSED_DATA_TBL  
        (PD_ID,  
        STORE,  
        SALES_NBR,  
        UNIT_COST,  
        ST_FLAG,  
        ST_DATE,  
        ST,  
        START_QTY,  
        START_VALUE,  
        START_ON_ORDER,  
        HAND,  
        ORDERED,  
        COMMITED,  
        SALES,  
        RECEIVE,  
        VALUED,  
        ID_1,  
        ID_2,  
        ID_3,  
        UNIT_PRICE,  
        EFFECTIVE_DATE,  
        STATUS,  
        STATUS_DATE,  
        STATUS_REASON)  
        VALUES (IDDATA   
              ,store  
              ,SalesNo  
              ,UnitCost         
              ,StWac  
              ,StDt           
              ,St          
              ,StartQty           
              ,StartValue         
              ,StartOnOrder       
              ,Hand      
              ,Ordered     
              ,COMMITED      
              ,Sales       
              ,Rec      
              ,Valued    
              ,Id1            
              ,Id2            
              ,Id3            
              ,UnitPrice     
              ,to_Date(EffectiveDate||' '||EffectiveTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
              ,'N'      
              ,SYSDATE  
              ,'XML PROCESS INSERT')      
        WITH T AS 
        ( SELECT STG.XML_DOCUMENT FROM STAGE_TBL STG WHERE STG.ID = IDDATA)         
--      This is to parse and fetch the data from XML              
        SELECT E.* FROM T, XMLTABLE('rp_send/rp_sendRow' PASSING T.XML_DOCUMENT COLUMNS
                               store            VARCHAR(20) PATH 'store'   
                              ,SalesNo          VARCHAR(20) PATH 'sales'  
                              ,UnitCost         NUMBER      PATH 'cost'  
                              ,StWac            VARCHAR(20) PATH 'flag'  
                              ,StDt             DATE        PATH 'st-dt'  
                              ,St               NUMBER      PATH 'st'  
                              ,StartQty         NUMBER      PATH 'qty'  
                              ,StartValue       NUMBER      PATH 'value'  
                              ,StartOnOrder     NUMBER      PATH 'start-on-order'  
                              ,Hand             NUMBER      PATH 'hand'  
                              ,Ordered            NUMBER      PATH 'order'  
                              ,Commited           NUMBER      PATH 'commit'  
                              ,Sales            NUMBER      PATH 'sales'  
                              ,Rec              NUMBER      PATH 'rec'  
                              ,Valued            NUMBER      PATH 'val'  
                              ,Id1              VARCHAR(30) PATH 'id-1'  
                              ,Id2              VARCHAR(30) PATH 'id-2'  
                              ,Id3              VARCHAR(30) PATH 'id-3'  
                              ,UnitPrice        NUMBER      PATH 'unit-pr'  
                              ,EffectiveDate    VARCHAR(30) PATH 'eff-dt'  
                              ,EffectiveTime    VARCHAR(30) PATH 'eff-tm'  
        ) E;     
      ROW_COUNT           := SQL%ROWCOUNT;  -- Not the # of all the rows inserted. 
      PROCESS_STATUS      := STATUS.PROCESSED;
      IF ROW_COUNT < 1 THEN       -- The insert failed Row Count = 0  No exception thrown 
        PROCESS_STATUS      := STATUS.ERROR;
        STATUS_DESCRIPTION  := 'ERROR Did not insert into Pos Inventory. Reason Unknown';
      END IF;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROW_COUNT           := 0;
        PROCESS_STATUS      := STATUS.ERROR;
        STATUS_DESCRIPTION  := 'SqlCode:' || SQLCODE || ' SqlErrMsg:' || SQLERRM;
END;


BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.enable(NULL);
  FOR A_NewStage IN NewStage
  LOOP
      READ_COUNT := READ_COUNT + 1;
      STAGE_TBL_PROCESS(A_NewStage.ID, PROCESS_STATUS, STATUS_DESCRIPTION, ROW_COUNT);
      INSERT_COUNT_TOTAL := INSERT_COUNT_TOTAL + ROW_COUNT;
      IF(ROW_COUNT <= 0 OR PROCESS_STATUS = STATUS.ERROR) THEN
          ERROR_COUNT := ERROR_COUNT + 1;
          UPDATE STAGE_TBL 
          SET status              = PROCESS_STATUS,
              status_DATE         = SYSDATE,
              status_DESCRIPTION  = STATUS_DESCRIPTION
          WHERE ID                  = A_NewStage.ID; 
        ELSE 
          UPDATE STAGE_TBL 
          SET status              = PROCESS_STATUS,
              status_DATE         = SYSDATE,
              status_DESCRIPTION  = STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
              SHRED_DT                = SYSDATE
          WHERE ID                  = A_NewStage.ID; 
        END IF; 
        COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
  IF ERROR_COUNT > 0 THEN
     ERRMSG := '** ERROR: ' || ERROR_COUNT || ' Stage records did not insert in to the Processed table correctly';
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,ErrMsg);  
  END IF;
    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
          RAISE;
END ;

/*
This one is taking 10 seconds to process an XML with about 2000 rp_sendRow elements
*/
DECLARE
  CURSOR NewStage IS
        SELECT * 
        FROM STAGE_TBL
        WHERE  status = 'N' 
        ORDER BY PUT_TIME ASC;
      SUBTYPE rt_NewStage IS NewStage % rowtype;

  ROW_COUNT           INTEGER := 0;   -- Return value from calling the procedure
  READ_COUNT          INTEGER := 0;   -- Number of rows read from the stage table
  INSERT_COUNT_TOTAL  INTEGER := 0;   -- Number of Inserts Inven records
  ERROR_COUNT         INTEGER := 0;   -- Number of Inven inserts that did inserted more then 1 row in Inven
  PROCESS_STATUS      STATUS.MmsStatus;
  STATUS_DESCRIPTION  STATUS.MmsStatusReason;
  ERRMSG              VARCHAR2(500);

PROCEDURE STAGE_TBL_PROCESS (IDDATA IN RAW, xData IN STAGE_TBL.XML_DOCUMENT%TYPE, PROCESS_STATUS OUT VARCHAR2, STATUS_DESCRIPTION OUT VARCHAR2, ROW_COUNT   OUT NUMBER) AS 
/*
  This procedure is to parse the XML from STAGE_TBL and populate the data from XML to PROCESSED_DATA_TBL table

  IN PARAMS
  ----------
  IDDATA              -   ID from STAGE_TBL
  xData                 -   XMLType field from XML_DOCUMENT of STAGE_TBL

  OUT PARAMS
  -----------
  PROCESS_STATUS        -   The STATUS of parsing and populating PROCESSED_DATA_TBL
  STATUS_DESCRIPTION    -   The description of the STATUS of parsing and populating PROCESSED_DATA_TBL
  ROW_COUNT             -   Number of rows inserted into PROCESSED_DATA_TBL
*/
BEGIN
     INSERT ALL INTO PROCESSED_DATA_TBL  
        (PD_ID,  
        STORE,  
        SALES_NBR,  
        UNIT_COST,  
        ST_FLAG,  
        ST_DATE,  
        ST,  
        START_QTY,  
        START_VALUE,  
        START_ON_ORDER,  
        HAND,  
        ORDERED,  
        COMMITED,  
        SALES,  
        RECEIVE,  
        VALUED,  
        ID_1,  
        ID_2,  
        ID_3,  
        UNIT_PRICE,  
        EFFECTIVE_DATE,  
        STATUS,  
        STATUS_DATE,  
        STATUS_REASON)  
        VALUES (IDDATA   
              ,store  
              ,SalesNo  
              ,UnitCost         
              ,StWac  
              ,StDt           
              ,St          
              ,StartQty           
              ,StartValue         
              ,StartOnOrder       
              ,Hand      
              ,Ordered     
              ,COMMITED      
              ,Sales       
              ,Rec      
              ,Valued    
              ,Id1            
              ,Id2            
              ,Id3            
              ,UnitPrice     
              ,to_Date(EffectiveDate||' '||EffectiveTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
              ,'N'      
              ,SYSDATE  
              ,'XML PROCESS INSERT')      
--      This is to parse and fetch the data from XML              
        SELECT E.* FROM XMLTABLE('rp_send/rp_sendRow' PASSING xDATA COLUMNS
                               store            VARCHAR(20) PATH 'store'   
                              ,SalesNo          VARCHAR(20) PATH 'sales'  
                              ,UnitCost         NUMBER      PATH 'cost'  
                              ,StWac            VARCHAR(20) PATH 'flag'  
                              ,StDt             DATE        PATH 'st-dt'  
                              ,St               NUMBER      PATH 'st'  
                              ,StartQty         NUMBER      PATH 'qty'  
                              ,StartValue       NUMBER      PATH 'value'  
                              ,StartOnOrder     NUMBER      PATH 'start-on-order'  
                              ,Hand             NUMBER      PATH 'hand'  
                              ,Ordered            NUMBER      PATH 'order'  
                              ,Commited           NUMBER      PATH 'commit'  
                              ,Sales            NUMBER      PATH 'sales'  
                              ,Rec              NUMBER      PATH 'rec'  
                              ,Valued            NUMBER      PATH 'val'  
                              ,Id1              VARCHAR(30) PATH 'id-1'  
                              ,Id2              VARCHAR(30) PATH 'id-2'  
                              ,Id3              VARCHAR(30) PATH 'id-3'  
                              ,UnitPrice        NUMBER      PATH 'unit-pr'  
                              ,EffectiveDate    VARCHAR(30) PATH 'eff-dt'  
                              ,EffectiveTime    VARCHAR(30) PATH 'eff-tm'  
        ) E;     
      ROW_COUNT           := SQL%ROWCOUNT;  -- Not the # of all the rows inserted. 
      PROCESS_STATUS      := STATUS.PROCESSED;
      IF ROW_COUNT < 1 THEN       -- The insert failed Row Count = 0  No exception thrown 
        PROCESS_STATUS      := STATUS.ERROR;
        STATUS_DESCRIPTION  := 'ERROR Did not insert into Pos Inventory. Reason Unknown';
      END IF;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROW_COUNT           := 0;
        PROCESS_STATUS      := STATUS.ERROR;
        STATUS_DESCRIPTION  := 'SqlCode:' || SQLCODE || ' SqlErrMsg:' || SQLERRM;
END;


BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.enable(NULL);
  FOR A_NewStage IN NewStage
  LOOP
      READ_COUNT := READ_COUNT + 1;
      STAGE_TBL_PROCESS(A_NewStage.ID, A_NewStage.XML_DOCUMENT, PROCESS_STATUS, STATUS_DESCRIPTION, ROW_COUNT);
      INSERT_COUNT_TOTAL := INSERT_COUNT_TOTAL + ROW_COUNT;
      IF(ROW_COUNT <= 0 OR PROCESS_STATUS = STATUS.ERROR) THEN
          ERROR_COUNT := ERROR_COUNT + 1;
          UPDATE STAGE_TBL 
          SET status              = PROCESS_STATUS,
              status_DATE         = SYSDATE,
              status_DESCRIPTION  = STATUS_DESCRIPTION
          WHERE ID                  = A_NewStage.ID; 
        ELSE 
          UPDATE STAGE_TBL 
          SET status              = PROCESS_STATUS,
              status_DATE         = SYSDATE,
              status_DESCRIPTION  = STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
              SHRED_DT                = SYSDATE
          WHERE ID                  = A_NewStage.ID; 
        END IF; 
        COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
  IF ERROR_COUNT > 0 THEN
     ERRMSG := '** ERROR: ' || ERROR_COUNT || ' Stage records did not insert in to the Processed table correctly';
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,ErrMsg);  
  END IF;
    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
          RAISE;
END ;

My XML with just one rp_sendRow element, it can go upto 2000 rp_sendRow elements 
<?xml version = \"1.0\" encoding = \"UTF-8\"?>  
<rp_send xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">  
    <rp_sendRow>  
        <store>0123</store>  
        <sales>022399190</sales>  
        <cost>0.01</cost>  
        <flag>true</flag>  
        <st-dt>2013-04-19</st-dt>  
        <st>146.51</st>  
        <qty>13.0</qty>  
        <value>0.0</value>  
        <start-on-order>0.0</start-on-order>  
        <hand>0.0</hand>  
        <order>0.0</order>  
        <commit>0.0</commit>  
        <sales>0.0</sales>  
        <rec>0.0</rec>  
        <val>0.0</val>  
        <id-1/>  
        <id-2/>  
        <id-3/>  
        <unit-pr>13.0</unit-pr>  
        <eff-dt>2015-06-16</eff-dt>  
        <eff-tm>09:12:21</eff-tm>  
    </rp_sendRow>  
</rp_send>
```

Comment: What happens if you add a `NOCOPY` to the declaration of the parameter to ask the compiler to pass by reference rather than passing by value?

Comment: @JustinCave Unnfortunately, I cant add NOCOPY for an IN param. If I add it throws a compilation error.

Comment: Try to use dbms_profiler. Maybe it will show where you spend most of the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OTN and AskTom, the issue is with the version of the PLSQL and how its parsed in each version.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9522467800346460591
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3797202

Parsing depends on storage type and its inefficient in pre 11.2.0.4 versions of PL/SQL

In version prior to 11.2.0.4, Oracle uses a functional evaluation based on an in-memory DOM-like representation of the XML document. And thats why the performance hit.

Comment: We tested this and confirmed that the Execution plan for XML passing as param is different from the execution plan of fetching XML from table as per OTN comments